# calculate a value from one schema and put that value in another schema mongodb node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({

            title: {type: String},
            rating : {type: Number},
            ingredients : { type: String}
});

var IngredientSchema = new Schema({

            title: {type: String},
            weightage : {type: String}
});
```

Example: In the ProductSchema, Ingredients field is: "Water, Zincum, Urea, Silica, Sodium"

Each ingredient is defined by the IngredientSchema

Example:

```
title : Water | Zincum | Urea | Silica | Sodium
weightage: 5 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 9
```

Now i have a formula to calculate product rating:
[sum of weightage of all ingredients] / [num of ingredients in product]

In our example: rating = (5 + 7 + 3 + 2 + 9)/5 = 5.2

now in api to add product , i want to calculate the rating based on the Ingredients field of Product and then store in database.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the `Ingredient` to `Product` Schema.
Use the mongoose populate.

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({

        title: {type: String},
        rating : {type: Number},
        ingredients : { Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient'}
    });

var IngredientSchema = new Schema({

        title: {type: String},
        weightage : {type: String}
    });
```

READ FURTHER:[here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)

Comment: can you please tell me how to apply the formula?

Comment: If you are making an app you can easily do the above in backend,just add another field of count to the productSchema.

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand... please could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You could implement the formula in your backend such that whenever you get product and its ingredient info you just put them in the formula and save it to the db. Product and its ingredients are not dyanamic so what to worry about?

Comment: in product schema, the ingredients would be a bunch of ingredient titles separated by commas, now how to apply the Schema.ObjectId reference to access weightage of each?

Comment: I myself have to study this why dont you google "adding ratings using mongoose". You will surely come up with something.